# Trying to regex match a line in a log file that contains my "app" variable without file extension

Tags: java, regex, groovy

I apologise as I am new to groovy but,

There is a line in my log file:

[INFO] Uploading: //blah/client_website-versionnumber.war

I have a variable established from an SQL statement "apps" which is:
client_website.war

My problem is I can't work out how to form an if statement to find this "client_website.war" in the log file, because there is a "-versionnumber" right in the middle of the variable in between client-website and .war. Is there a way to match half of my apps variable or something? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem (and judging from the lack of answers so far, others don't seem to, either). Could you edit your post to show the code you're using so far (including the regex that isn't working yet)? More information about what a version number may look like would also be helpful.

Comment: so for example the log would say:
client-website-12.0.0.war
however, I have a variable apps = client-website.war.
I do not know how to search the log for my variable, because the version number will prevent a regex match

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to define a collection/range of allowed characters for your version number. For example,

```
client_website[0-9.-]*\.war
```

would match `client_website`, followed by zero or more (`*`) characters from the collection "any ASCII digit (`0-9`), dot (`.`) or dash (`-`)", followed by  `\.war`.

This would also match nonsensical values like `client_website.....war` or `client_website-.-.-.-.war`, but if you don't need to exclude such values, that regex should do fine.

If you decide to extend the character class, make sure that the dash remains at the end of the class; otherwise it would be interpreted as a range indicator (as in `0-9`!).